# Treuegelübde anderer Ländern abzuschwören - a mix of dative and genitive

Tags: dative, genitive

I'm reading https://de.wikihow.com/Sich-um-die-amerikanische-Staatsangeh%C3%B6rigkeit-bewerben and wonder why it says "Dabei versprichst du:
Treuegelübde anderer Ländern abzuschwören"

I see https://en.pons.com/translate/german-english/abschw%C3%B6ren that abschwören requires the dative, so I guess it should have been "anderen Ländern". Would you agree?

Comment: For the record: I have now fixed the error in the WikiHow page (or at least triggered the change, I guess someone still has to accept it because I'm a new contributor there).

Answer (score 5):

There are two cases involved here, dative and genitive. You're correct that "abschwören" requires the dative, so it needs to be

> (Man muss) Treuegelübden abschwören.

But the part about the other countries needs to be in genitive (*Whose* pledges of allegiance do you need to recant? The pledges of allegiance *of other countries*). So it needs to be

> (Man muss) Treuegelübden anderer Länder abschwören.

It looks like there's a superfluous "n" in the example.

Another example would be

> Sie führt die Hunde anderer Leute Gassi.

in which "die Hunde" is accusative, but "anderer Leute" needs to be genitive.